# Database Scripts Compare .sql files for Forensic Analysis

Tags: database, compare

I need to do the comparing/forensic to find out the difference between old database containing tampered data and the current state. The old database consist of some 25 .sql files. I have some hints on the tables where it might have been tampered. What could be the best and fastest approach to find out what data was tampered.

Comment: I should probably flag this as too broad, but I'm just going to leave a link here to [ask] and hope someone has a quick and easy answer for you.  If not, you'll get a lot more response if you try *something* yourself and come with specific questions on implementation.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I am new to stack overflow, may be i need to rephrase question.

Comment: Daniel, I rephrased it, hopeful you will not have objection now. 

Its not about I am not trying anything and coming for the help here, I am asking for the approach to help me get to know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your .sql files are exported text files. Winmerge can be useful to compare the old and newer versions. If you really want to do a forensic investigation you should keep in mind that there may be deleted content in the Database....

Comment: For me kdiff3 seems to do a better compare operation that Winmerge, but of course, it all boils down to preference, and whatever to you believe works best.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will check this out!